# read file matching lines using array using php

Tags: php

I want to be able to read through a plain text file and match a number of lines without the need to iterate over the text file multiple times. I am passing in an array with a list of strings I would like to match, which ideally, I would like to put into an array.

I can achieve the desired result using the code below, but it necessitates the reading of the text file multiple times.

```
function readFile($line){
  $contents = file("test.txt");

  if(preg_match("/$line*/i", $val)){
    return($val);
  }
}
```

Ideally, I would like to do the following:

```
// pass an array to the funciton which will parse the file once and match on the elements defined.
$v = readFile(array("test_1", "test_2", "test_2", "test_3"));

// return an array with the matched elements from the search.
print_r($v);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks all!

Comment: you already know the solution: iterate the file once and check each line for the search term. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$val = array();
foreach ($contents as $file) {
   foreach ($line as $l) {
      if (stristr($file, $l)) {
         $val[] = $file;
         break; // Don't need to check the other $line values
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Solution worked - thanks for all the help - much appreciataed!

Answer (score 0):

```
$val = array();
foreach ($contents as $file) {
   foreach ($line as $l) {
      if (stristr($file, $l) {
         $val[] = $file;
      }
   }
}
```

Even if you want to stick with `preg_match`, the "*" is unnecessary.

Comment: You probably want to add a `break;` statement, so that if `$file` matches multiple strings it's only added to `$val` once.

Comment: @Barmar I would think he would want *every* occurrence added, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Would probably be better to have it as Explosion Pills has it, so that he can work with the array rather than reloading the file over and over

Comment: I meant break out of the inner loop, not the outer loop. Otherwise you can add the same line multiple times.

Comment: @Barmar you are adding a line from `file` every time `l` matches.  As far as we know, `l` could just be `"a"`, so it would match many lines and a `break` would be counterintuitive.  However, you could use `array_unique` on the file if you only want unique occurrences.